# I'm having an issue with linked list of structures in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have to create a linked list of structures Book, my problem is when I create a new node and enter the properties of a new book inside of it, all of my previous books in previous nodes change their names to that last one I entered, although the year of publishing remains original. Can someone explain how this works, and what I have to do to make it work properly?

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 255

struct Book {
    char *title;
    int year;
};

struct Node {
    struct Book book;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Book createBook(char *title, int year) {
    struct Book book = {title, year};
    return book;
}

void print(struct Node *head) {
    struct Node *curr_node = head;

    while (curr_node != NULL) {
        printf("%s(%d)\n", curr_node->book.title, curr_node->book.year);
        curr_node = curr_node->next;
    }
}

void add(struct Node **head, struct Book book) {
    struct Node *new_node;
    struct Book *new_book;
    new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof( struct Node ));

    new_book = &new_node->book;

    new_book->title = book.title;
    new_book->year = book.year;

    new_node->next = (*head);
    *head = new_node;
}

void pop(struct Node **head) {
    struct Node *next_node = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty!");
        return;
    }

    next_node = (*head)->next;
    free(*head);
    *head = next_node;
}

void reverse(struct Node **head) {
    struct Node *prev_node = NULL;
    struct Node *curr_node = *head;
    struct Node *next_node = NULL;

    while (curr_node != NULL) {
        next_node = curr_node->next;
        curr_node->next = prev_node;
        prev_node = curr_node;
        curr_node = next_node;
    }

    *head = prev_node;
}

void clear(struct Node **head) {

    struct Node *curr_node = *head;
    struct Node *temp_node = NULL;

    while (curr_node != NULL) {
        temp_node = curr_node->next;
        free(curr_node);
        curr_node = temp_node;
    }

    *head = NULL;
}

int main() {

    struct Node *head = NULL;

    short process = 1; // 1 for True 0 for False
    int option = 0;
    char title[N];
    int year = 0;

    while (process) {

        printf("List of actions:\n");
        printf("1:\tAdd element\n");
        printf("2:\tRemove element\n");
        printf("3:\tReverse list\n");
        printf("4:\tPrint list\n");
        printf("5:\tClear list\n");
        printf("0:\tExit\n");

        scanf("%d", &option);

        switch (option) {

            case 1:
                printf("Enter book\'s title: ");
                scanf("%s", title);
                printf("Enter book\'s year of publishing: ");
                scanf("%d", &year);
                add(&head, createBook(title, year));
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                pop(&head);
                break;
            case 3:
                reverse(&head);
                break;
            case 4:
                print(head);
                break;
            case 5:
                clear(&head);
                break;
            case 0:
                process = 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("\n");
                printf("**************************\n");
                printf("Enter numbers from 1 to 5!\n");
                printf("**************************\n");
                printf("\n");
                continue;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not add C++ tag to C questions next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are always passing a pointer to the same local array `title` declared in main

```
 char title[N];
```

to the function `createBook`

```
add(&head, createBook(title, year));
```

So the data member `title` of all nodes

```
struct Book {
    char *title;
    int year;
};
```

points to the same local array `title` declared in `main` due to this initialization within the function

```
struct Book book = {title, year};
```

That is the local array `title` declared in `main` used as an argument expression of the function `createBook` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. And all function calls deal with the same address of the first element of the array.

You need to allocate dynamically a copy of the referenced array `title` for each node.

Another approach is to declare the data member `title` of the structure `Book` as having a character array type instead of the pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, now everything works!

I allocated memory for my char pointer in while loop in main function right before switch statement:

`char *title = (char *) calloc(N, sizeof(char));`

So now the working code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N 255

struct Book {
    char *title;
    int year;
};

struct Node {
    struct Book book;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Book createBook(char *title, int year) {
    struct Book book = {title, year};
    return book;
}

void print(struct Node *head) {
    struct Node *curr_node = head;

    while (curr_node != NULL) {
        printf("%s(%d)\n", curr_node->book.title, curr_node->book.year);
        curr_node = curr_node->next;
    }
}

void add(struct Node **head, struct Book book) {
    struct Node *new_node;
    struct Book *new_book;
    new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof( struct Node ));

    new_book = &new_node->book;

    new_book->title = book.title;
    new_book->year = book.year;

    new_node->next = (*head);
    *head = new_node;
}

void pop(struct Node **head) {
    struct Node *next_node = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty!");
        return;
    }

    next_node = (*head)->next;
    free(*head);
    *head = next_node;
}

void reverse(struct Node **head) {
    struct Node *prev_node = NULL;
    struct Node *curr_node = *head;
    struct Node *next_node = NULL;

    while (curr_node != NULL) {
        next_node = curr_node->next;
        curr_node->next = prev_node;
        prev_node = curr_node;
        curr_node = next_node;
    }

    *head = prev_node;
}

void clear(struct Node **head) {

    struct Node *curr_node = *head;
    struct Node *temp_node = NULL;

    while (curr_node != NULL) {
        temp_node = curr_node->next;
        free(curr_node);
        curr_node = temp_node;
    }

    *head = NULL;
}

int main() {

    struct Node *head = NULL;

    short process = 1; // 1 for True 0 for False
    int option = 0;

    int year = 0;

    while (process) {

        printf("List of actions:\n");
        printf("1:\tAdd element\n");
        printf("2:\tRemove element\n");
        printf("3:\tReverse list\n");
        printf("4:\tPrint list\n");
        printf("5:\tClear list\n");
        printf("0:\tExit\n");

        scanf("%d", &option);
        char *title = (char *) calloc(N, sizeof(char));
        switch (option) {

            case 1:

                printf("Enter book\'s title: ");
                scanf("%s", title);
                printf("Enter book\'s year of publishing: ");
                scanf("%d", &year);
                add(&head, createBook(title, year));
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                pop(&head);
                break;
            case 3:
                reverse(&head);
                break;
            case 4:
                print(head);
                break;
            case 5:
                clear(&head);
                break;
            case 0:
                process = 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("\n");
                printf("**************************\n");
                printf("Enter numbers from 1 to 5!\n");
                printf("**************************\n");
                printf("\n");
                continue;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```